# jQuery filtering selector to remove nested elements matching pattern

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this sample markup (assuming a random number of elements between `.outer` and `.inner`:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can set up jQuery to select the outer and inner divs as such:

```
$outer = $('.outer');
$inner = $outer.find('.inner')
```

Works fine.

However, let's say I want to allow an unlimited nesting of this logic, so I may have this:

```
<div class="outer"> div a
    <div class="inner"> div b
        <div class="outer"> div c
            <div class="inner"> div d </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In that situation, when selecting div a via `.outer` I want to match it with only div b. In otherwords, I want to exclude ancestors of a nested `.outer` ancestor.

I'd like to have parings of outer and inner(s) contained within their nesting level.

I'm hoping `.filter()` could pull it off, but can't think of a selector that would work universally for unlimited nested patterns. Is it doable using a filter? Or maybe even a direct selector pattern?

UPDATE:

I think something like this could work, but not sure how one can (or if it's allowed) reference 'this' within a selector:

```
$outer = $('.outer');
$inner = $outer.not('this .outer').find('.inner')
```

UPDATE 2:

I should have mentioned this intially: `.inner` will always be a descendant of `.outer` but not necessarily an immediate child.

UPDATE 3:

Here's some test samples of HTML that could be used. In each case, I'd want to be able to select the .outer and pair up the .inner's it contains between itself and the nested outer. For clarity, I added names to each div (outer-x pairs with inner-x)

```
//sample 1
<div class="outer"> outer-a
    <div>
        <div class="inner"> inner-a
            <div class="outer"> inner-b
                <div class="inner"> inner-b </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="inner"> inner-a </div>
    </div>
</div>

//sample 2
<div class="outer"> outer-a
        <div class="inner"> inner-a
            <div class="outer"> inner-b
                <div>
                    <div class="inner"> inner-b </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

//sample 3
<div class="outer"> outer-a
        <div class="inner"> inner-a
            <div class="outer"> inner-b
                <div class="inner"> inner-b
                    <div class="outer"> outer-c 
                        <div class="inner"> inner-c</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

//bonus sample (we're trying to avoid this)
<div class="outer"> outer-a
        <div class="inner outer"> inner-a outer-b
            <div class="inner"> inner-b </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE 4

I think I ended up going down a similar path as gnarf. I ended up with this:

```
var $outer = $('.outer');
var $inner = $outer.find('.inner').filter(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        return $(this).closest('.outer') == $outer; 
  });                                                                  
});
```

Am I on the right track there? It's not working so I assume I have a bit of a logic error still.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - even if you match the first nest and only remove that - its children would be removed anyway

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another option. Suppose you have the `.outer` `o`, this will select all `inner`s under it:

```
o.find('.inner').not(o.find('.outer .inner'))
```

It should work identically to gnarf's answer, but a bit simpler.

First, it finds all `inner`s under this `outer`.
Next, remove all `inners` that are descendants of other `outers`

Interactive working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zb9gF/

Selector performance seems to be much better using this method as opposed to the `.filter()` as well: http://jsperf.com/selector-test-find-not

Comment: Brilliant! As usual, the answer is simpler than the path I end up heading down. I was struggling with the syntax needed to combined a cached object with a css selector and the find() logic didn't occure to me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the question is very interesting and challenging, it took a lot of work to get to this simple line...

Comment: Nice optimization, wish I'd thought of it first :) -- Was just playin with the usefulness of [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) yesterday for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089045).

Comment: why do you need to find outers at first? why not to look just for inners and then get closest outers? see my comment also

Comment: Hey, this question qualifies me for the silver `jQuery` badge!

Comment: it just finds your answer to be awesome than =)

Comment: @Kobi - Grats - I'm sitting pretty close myself - [as seen on odata](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag?UserId=91914) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.outer').children('.inner');
```

That would select any `inner` that sits immediately below an `outer`. I'm not really clear on which div you're trying to select for. Is it a, b, c, or d? Having something called outer nested within something called inner doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Maybe if you could provide a more specific example?

Comment: +1 - This is probably the best bet assuming that the `.inner` is always a direct child of the `.outer` and not nested another level down...

Comment: sorry for not clarifying that. That is, indeed, a variable. Inner will be a descendant, but not necessarily an immediate child.

Answer (score 2):

If the `.inner` are always direct children of `.outer`s - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) is probably your best bet (jasongetsdown's answer)

If you need something that looks even deeper, you could do something like this:

```
var $outer = $('.outer').first(); // grab the first .outer
$outer.find('.inner').filter(function() {
    // only if the closest parent .outer is the same as the .outer we are looking in
    return $(this).closest('.outer').get(0) == $outer.get(0);
}).css('border','1px solid #000');
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/sj9LV/)

Comment: @gnarf...I think that's close to what I was thinking too. I added an update to my post that uses a filter function as well. Mine doesn't work so will try your syntax next!

Comment: By the way, +1 an hour ago, nice one. I'm pretty sure you are correct, this seems like the right logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some css magic:

```
$('.outer>.inner')
```

Shold give you only first level of `.inner` elements. :)

Comment: That selector will match both `.inner`'s

Answer (score 1):

If assume correctly you want to select all `.inner` that is beneath an `.outer`, except if there is an `.outer` inbetween, perhaps following will work (untested):

```
$('.outer:not(.inner):has(:not(.outer) .inner:not(.outer), > .inner:not(.outer))');
```

updated after test on OP example HTML at http://jsfiddle.net/cEwBT/1/

Comment: Your assumption is correct. However, that sample won't work. I first cache 'outer' and then want to find all inners that aren't a child of a nested outer. The catch is that my cached outer *is* a .outer so would be excluding itself.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why not to select `.inner` at first, and then get `closest` `.outer` ?

```
$inner = $('.inner');
$outer = $inner.closest('.outer');
```

in case some inner blocks could be not within outer blocks at all, use this first line instead

`$inner = $('.outer .inner');`

Comment: The question here is in the other direction. Given *one* `outer`, how do you find its `inner` divs?

Comment: see. my question is why not to go other direction. having .outer given, Kobi's answer works perfect. but if you just need to get all inners for all outers - may be you could start from scratch so to say