# jQuery - select class not contained in another class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery filtering selector to remove nested elements matching pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096098/jquery-filtering-selector-to-remove-nested-elements-matching-pattern)

I have a hierarchy of groups.  Something like:

```
<div class="group">
    <span class="child"></span>
    <div class="group">
        <span class="child"></span>
        <span class="child"></span>
        <span class="child"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <div>This child is farther down <span class="child"></span></div>
</div>
```

How can I select the children in each group, without selecting any subgroup's children?

```
$(".group").each(function() {
    // Wrong, click fires twice (the 1st level group selects 2nd level children)
    var children = $(this).children(".child");

    // Wrong, click fires twice
    children = $(this).children(":not(.group) .child");

    // How can I properly do this??

    children.click(function() {
        alert("children.click");
    });
});
```

I've also tried `find()` instead of `children()` but I can't seem to get this to work correctly.  Also, I can't use direct children (or `>`) because the descendants could be inside other non-.gorup HTML tags (i.e. several DOM levels down).

Comment: Mmmh I tried in jsfiddle and the click is not fired twice... but anyway, you might want use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: What do you mean that the children can be several layers down? No matter what the structure, .group > .child picks up the groupings you need given that DOM layout.

Comment: Children != descendants. *Children* can only be one layer down...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096098/jquery-filtering-selector-to-remove-nested-elements-matching-pattern/3096944#3096944 -- Basically boils down to `var $g = $(this), children = $g.find('.child').not($g.find('.group .child'));` as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb9gF/).  Also, don't forget the `click` event will propagate to a parent `.child` unless you `return false`

Comment: I think @gnarf is right.  I'll test that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.child` is always a direct descendant of its group, then `>` selector will work, as noted. Otherwise, you can filter set with a function

```
var group = this;
$(group).find('.child').filter(function() {
    // check if current element belongs to our group
    return $(this).closest('.group')[0] == group;
})
```

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/KxnTZ/)

Comment: I think both gnarf and you have it right.  I'm thinking yours would be faster because it only has to go up the tree a few nodes, but it does have to do it for every child so I'm not completely sure.  This is a closer version to what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/KxnTZ/2/

Comment: @Nelson Version with _not_ also processes every child, so I think they should have comparable speeds. Although, it depends on how effective is substruction of sets in jquery: if _a.not(b)_ means every element of _a_ is compared to every element of _b_, that would be bad.

Comment: So my REAL problem was I actually needed to select a checkbox inside the span.  So I had something comparable to `$(group).find(".child").filter(...).find(":checkbox")`.  Of course that last find didn't stay within the boundaries since we already filtered before.  Your example (which worked) helped me find this error.

Comment: The `.find().not(.find())` seems MUCH faster: http://jsperf.com/selector-test-find-not

Comment: @gnarf Thanks! Should bookmark that website.

Comment: @gnarf - I'll go with not() then since the syntax is also easier on the eyes.  I really should be giving you the correct answer, though you were right it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the direct children of a group you can try something like:

```
$('.group > .child').click(function(){
    alert('You clicked on: '+$(this).text());
});
```

See documentation at [jQuery: child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

EDIT: else you might want to check out the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096098/jquery-filtering-selector-to-remove-nested-elements-matching-pattern/) posted by gnarf

Comment: I added some more info which you may have missed.  The children could be inside other non-.group HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is also very readable:

```
$(".group").each(function() {
  var allChilds = $(this).find('.child');
  var subChilds = $(this).find('.group .child');

  var firstChilds = allChilds.not(subChilds);
  firstChilds.css({ color: 'red' });
});
```