# Is it possible to write onFocus/lostFocus handler for a DIV using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onfocus, lost-focus

I have a div and when the user clicks the div a function should be called. And when the user clicks something else (anything other than this div) another function should be called.

So basically i need to have onFocus() and lostFocus() function calls associated with this DIV. Is it available in JavaScript or even in jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: why you need onFocus  if you want to call function on Click event?

Comment: @Mohammad, Yes, i could make use of Click event instead of onFocus. But the problem is, i need to have the lostFocus event or something similar to it. Any idea?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to add `tabindex` attribute to `div` :

```js
$("#mydiv").focusin(function() {
  $("#mydiv").css("background", "red");
});
$("#mydiv").focusout(function() {
  $("#mydiv").css("background", "white");
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="100"></div>
<div id="anotherdiv"></div>
```

Comment: @Mohammad, Jashwant Thanks a lot for that answer guys. I saw the jsfiddle demo. Exactly what i wanted. But SADLY, this method isnt working in my code. It says => $("#mydiv").focusin is not a function.

Comment: @MohammadAdil, It worked. Cheers! :) May i know what is the relevence of TabIndex attr in this? Just being curios.

Comment: This method requires the JS code to be put in the document ready section, right?

Comment: you can put that in ready itself or inside a function that is called from ready --------And --tabindex is used to define a sequence that you follow when you use the Tab key to navigate through a page

Comment: This is because a div doesn't have a tabindex by default, and to use focusin and focusout  on an element ,it should have a tabindex,,that is why we are setting a tabindex to our div..

Answer (score 6):

Focus do not work on `DIV` : http://api.jquery.com/focus/

ALso good read: [jquery : focus to div is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965924/jquery-focus-to-div-is-not-working)

```
If you want to focus a div or anything normally can't be focused, set the tag's tabindex to -1 first.
eg: $("div#header").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

Comment: Your method worked and i got focus() working. Now how can i implement lostFocus()? blur() isn't working.

Comment: @Orbb Glad it helped: here you should take the code for lost focus / focus out from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088738/jquery-need-alternative-to-focusout `:)`

Comment: @Jashwant MAGIC `:))` hows it goin? Ah I will read your question latter and reply in more detail might be this week `:P`

Comment: @Jashwant lol :) not greedy for points Just want to give a `Quality` to your question `:))` great job in question though! <although ++ are always welcome and encouraging> :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution suits your web page, but you could use JQuery on() to attach a click event to the body element and delegate it to child div's. Then in your event handler, test the id attribute and handle as such; something like:

```
$(body).on("click", "div", function (evt) {
     if ($(this).attr("id") == "innerDiv") {
            handle inner div click here
     } else {
            hanlde out div click here
     {
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

Sure.

```
$("#your-div-id").focusin(function() {
    // code here
});

$("#your-div-id").focusout(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: it didnt work. I tried it as you suggested. Then i tried it with bind/live since the div is generated dynamically. But nope! :(