# Jquery. Binding the instantiation of a plugin on dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Having a problem selecting an id within a dynamically placed div tag on a page.

It's a date field and I'd like to have a datepicker show up when the user focuses on the field.  That I'm trying to set up a plugin instead of doing any other kind of jQuery event is, I think, my problem.

So here's the dynamically loaded content that is placed on the page when a user clicks one of several radio buttons in a "calendar".

```
$("#s10").click(function(){
    $("#S_Date").html('&lt;input type="text" name="Start_Date" id="Start_Date" value="2016-05-24" /&gt;2016-05-24');
```

`#S_Date` is the parent div id that is loaded when the document loads.

I'm using the "PickMeUp" datepicker plugin.

From what I can tell, I need to use the `on()` event handler but I just can't seem to get it to bind to `#Start_Date`.

Here's my latest attempt at trying to call it:

```
var pickitup = $("#Start_Date").pickmeup({format  : 'Y-m-d'});
$("#S_Date").on('focus', "#Start_Date", function(){pickitup});
```

With pickitup defined, I have also tried:

```
$("#S_Date").on('focus', "#Start_Date", pickitup);
```

`$("#S_Date").on('focus', "#Start_Date", function(){pickmeup({format  : 'Y-m-d'})});` fails out of the gate with a `pickmeup is not defined` error.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Yes, you would need event delegation: `$("#S_Date").on('focus', "#Start_Date", pickitup);`. But the problem is the parent _div_ does not support the `focus` event. You might try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280379/is-it-possible-to-write-onfocus-lostfocus-handler-for-a-div-using-js-or-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm understanding what you're doing, you want to insert some html into a given element on that click event, then apply the date picker functionality to it?

```
$("#s10").on("click", function() { //when the element is clicked...
  //create an input with the appropriate attributes
  var picker = $("<input />", { type: "text", name: "Start_Date", value: "2016-05-24" }); 
  //append it to the desired element(s)
  $("#S_Date").append(picker);
  //run the plugin on it
  picker.pickmeup({format: 'Y-m-d'});
});
```

Here's a working (simple) fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s6vu0rnq/

The undefined error you got was because "pickmeup" is a property of jquery's prototype, but you were trying to call it from the global scope.

Also, ".click" is just an alias for ".on", so you can use either.