# Set default button based on user focusing div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page with 2 sections, Search and Result. 
Each section has a button in it.

When the user focus on Search section and presses enter button, the search button should trigger.

Similarly, focusing on Result section and pressing enter button should trigger Save Changes button.

I tried the following code but, I am not getting the expected behavior. Any suggestion / guidance will be much appreciated.

```js
function SetDefaultButton(parentContainer, button) {
        $(document).off('keydown', parentContainer).
        on('keydown', parentContainer, function (event) {
            var eventTarget = event.target;
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(button).trigger('click');
            }
        });
    };
    
SetDefaultButton('#DivSearchSection', '#BtnSearch');

SetDefaultButton('#DivResultSection', '#BtnSave');

$('#BtnSearch').on('click', function(){
  alert('Search is triggered');
});

$('#BtnSave').on('click', function(){
  alert('Save is triggered');
});
```

```css
#DivSearchSection
{
  min-height:50px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

#DivResultSection
{
  min-height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:yellow;
}

button{
margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivContainer">
  <div id="DivSearchSection">
    This is search section.
    <button type="button" id="BtnSearch">Search</button>
  </div>  
  <div id="DivResultSection">
    This is result section.
    <button type="button" id="BtnSave">Save Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Attach an onfocus event handler](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) to your sections. You will need to add an [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute to your sections for it to work.

When the section gets focus, trigger the focus on its child button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#DivSearchSection, #DivResultSection').focus(function() {
    // trigger focus on the section's button when the section is focused
    $('button', this).focus();
  });

  $('#BtnSearch').on('click', function() {
    alert('Search is triggered');
  });

  $('#BtnSave').on('click', function() {
    alert('Save is triggered');
  });
});
```

```css
#DivSearchSection {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#DivResultSection {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivContainer">
  <!-- add tabindex -->
  <div id="DivSearchSection" tabindex="-1">
    This is search section.
    <button type="button" id="BtnSearch">Search</button>
  </div>
  <!-- add tabindex -->
  <div id="DivResultSection" tabindex="-1">
    This is result section.
    <button type="button" id="BtnSave">Save Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related: [Is it possible to write onFocus/lostFocus handler for a DIV using JS or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280379/is-it-possible-to-write-onfocus-lostfocus-handler-for-a-div-using-js-or-jquery)

Comment: What is the reason for giving -1 for tabindex?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh [Focus doesn't work on DIVs by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965965/1022914)